# Enclosing still not enclosed strings with paired delimiters

Tags: regex, perl

Need enclose still not enclosed strings with an paired delimiters. Example text:

```
Some text or random characters here. {% Another random string
enclosed in a pair of delimiters as next {% what can be deeply
nested {% as {%here%}%} end of delimited %} text. %}Another
bla-bla

random text outside of the delimiters - called
as "free text".
```

Need enclose all occurences of *free text* with

```
%{ORIG .... original free text ... %}
```

and don't modifying the strings what is already enclosed.
So, in the above example need enclose two sections of free text, and should get the next:

```
{%ORIG Some text or random characters here. %}{% Another random string
enclosed in a pair of delimiters as next {% what can be deeply
nested {% as {%here%}%} end of delimited %} text. %}{%ORIG Another
bla-bla

random text outside of the delimiters - called
as "free text".%}
```

So, the opening delimiter is `{%` and the closing is `%}`.

Questions:

- Is possible to do this with "regexes" or I need to write some parser for this?
- Exists some CPAN module what I can use for this task?

Comment: You should look hard at [Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) before going any further.  It is a core module in Perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with regex with help of [recursive subpattern calls like `(?R)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f_PARNO_%29-%28%3f-_PARNO_%29-%28%3f%2b_PARNO_%29-%28%3fR%29-%28%3f0%29).

For example:

```
$_ = <<'_STR_';
Some text or random characters here. {% Another random string
enclosed in a pair of delimiters as next {% what can be deeply
nested {% as {%here%}%} end of delimited %} text. %}Another
bla-bla

random text outside of the delimiters - called
as "free text".
_STR_

s/
  ( {% (?R)* %} )            # match balanced {% %} groups
|
  ( (?: (?! {% | %} ) . )+ ) # match everything except {% %}
/
  $1 ? $1 : "{%ORIG $2 %}";  # if {% ... %} matched, leave it as is. else enclose it
/gsex;

print;
```

Output:

```
{%ORIG Some text or random characters here.  %}{% Another random string
enclosed in a pair of delimiters as next {% what can be deeply
nested {% as {%here%}%} end of delimited %} text. %}{%ORIG Another
bla-bla

random text outside of the delimiters - called
as "free text".
 %}
```

Comment: Great regex solution. Only wondering, why added one space to the beginning of the last line.

Comment: @novacik, a space is always added in the replace before the `%}`. It's the last space in `"{%ORIG $2 %}"`. If you don't want that you can remove it. The `%}` is on its own last line because the string ends with a line break (a symptom of using `<<FOO` quoting).

Answer (score 4):

[Jonathan Leffler's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) suggestion is right. You can solve this problem using the `Text::Balanced` module with its `extract_tagged` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Balanced qw<extract_tagged>;

my ($open_delim, $close_delim) = qw( {% %} );

my $text = do { local $/ = undef; <> };
chomp $text;

while (1) {
    my @r = extract_tagged($text, $open_delim, $close_delim, '(?s).*?(?={%)', undef);
    if (length $r[2]) {
        printf qq|%sORIG %s%s|, $open_delim, $r[2], $close_delim;
    }   

    if (length $r[0]) {
        printf qq|%s|, $r[0];
    }   
    else {
        if (length $r[1]) {
            printf qq|%sORIG %s%s|, $open_delim, $r[1], $close_delim;
        }
        last;
    }   

    $text = $r[1];
}
```

This program does an infinite loop until there aren't more delimiters in the text. Until that moment, in each iteration it checks the prefix (text until an opening delimiter, `$r[2]`) and surrounds it with the delimiters, and for the text already surrounded with them (`$r[0]`), print it as is.

At the beginning I slurp the content of the whole file because this function only works with a scalar. You should take a look to the documentation to learn what the function returns, and I hope you get the idea that will help to solve your problem, in case it is far more complex than this example.

Just for testing, run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

That yields:

```
{%ORIG Some text or random characters here. %}{% Another random string
enclosed in a pair of delimiters as next {% what can be deeply
nested {% as {%here%}%} end of delimited %} text. %}{%ORIG Another
bla-bla

random text outside of the delimiters - called
as "free text".%}
```

Comment: couple of problems; avoid skipping prefix text of "0" by checking `if (length $r[2])`; avoid adding extra `{%ORIG %}` at the end when the text ends with delimited text by making the printf before last conditional on `length $r[1]`.

Comment: @ysth: Thank you for your suggestions. I've used the `defined()` check instead the `length()`, I think it's more accurate. For the second one, I don't know if I understood it right, but I've added the `ORIG` to the `printf()` format instead concat it.

Comment: no, that doesn't fix it.  you do need length, not defined, and you do need to not always do the print in the else clause.  Try input `{%%}` which should produce output `{%%}` but instead produces `{%ORIG %}{%%}{%ORIG %}` (the first extra orig because `$r[2]` is `''`, and your defined test incorrectly wraps and outputs it; the second because `$r[0]` is undef the second time through the loop, getting you into the else clause, but it should only `last`, not print anything, when `$r[1]` is `''`)

Comment: @ysth: Ah, ok. Now I think I got the bug. I've added an additional `length()` inside the `else` branch and seems to handle fine those cases that begin or end with the delimiters.